# What are some examples of configuration languages?

Tags: programming-languages

I've seen the term "configuration language" come up during the course of studying for the CSDA certification exam.

The formal definition provided is:

> Configuration languages create files usually read and interpreted only once, during initialization

I also know that one use of a configuration language is to create files that set the initial state of an application - this is a question on the practice exams.

What are some examples of configuration languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration languages are typically declarative. The most common example are Windows INI files, which are processed with using an API provided by Microsoft (or one of the many alternative implementations).

On Unix, many files in /etc follow some configuration language. A simple one would be [/etc/inittab](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/5inittab.man.html) (configuration language for /sbin/init), a more complex one is [sendmail.cf](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/readme.html) (configuration language for sendmail). Another example is [PAM configuration](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/pam/pam-config.html) (on Linux, typically in /etc/pam.d).

Comment: Would you say that CSS a configuration language? I'm having a hard time categorizing it.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like any language can be a configuration language. I'd imagine languages suited to this would be Bash and any of the scripting languages (PHP, Python, e.t.c.).

Comment: I was thinking those, but "scripting language" is another category that is defined as "a language used to connect two or more applications". I suppose there could be overlap between scripting language and configuration language, depending on how its used, though.